# what is the path of a base64 image?

Tags: c#

some google pictures has base64 images.
what is the path of that image 
here is the base64 jpeg from a google picture

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

e.g. if I take a Picturebox and use `Picturebox.Load(base64)` then I get an execption.
or is it specially made so that you don't get the path?

Comment: What _path_? There is no path.

Comment: That **is** the image. It's base64 encoded binary. The linked dupe should get you the answer. Just make sure you understand why.

Comment: @tkausl Is there no path behind that base64 image? like `www.google.com/images...jpg`

Comment: @Fildor well I think I now understand what that is thx :D